# Encrypted bluetooth file transfer

Tags: windows, encryption, bluetooth

When I transfer a file from my Windows 10 PC to my Android using Bluetooth (right click on a file -> Send to Bluetooth device) I can see that fsquirt.exe transfers the file to the Android device plain text (over sockets, with the Obex protocol). shouldn't the data over the sockets be encrypted?

Comment: No, by default it uses only Authentication. You have to implement custom file transfering with Encryption option turned ON.

Comment: What are you using to monitor the data transfer?

Comment: I see. I'm using debugger to monitor the buffer passed to WSASend() by fsquirt.exe

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth for Windows supports the following socket options. Socket options are set and queried using the **setsockopt** and **getsockopt** functions, respectively.

For disconnected sockets, the SO_BTH_AUTHENTICATE specifies that authentication is required for a connect or accept operation to complete successfully. Setting this socket option actively initiates authentication during connection establishment, if the two Bluetooth devices were not previously authenticated.

On unconnected sockets, the SO_BTH_ENCRYPT **socket option enforces encryption to establish a connection. Encryption is only available for authenticated connections.**

The SO_BTH_MTU socket option is an advanced option used primarily for validation.

So I think encryption is for authenticated connections, not for data transmitted by Bluetooth.

For details we can refer the article: [Bluetooth and Socket Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-socket-options)

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't the data over the sockets be encrypted?

No. Bluetooth provides encryption at link layer – e.g. similar to WPA2 for Wi-Fi.

But unlike TCP/IP traffic (which often travels across many links with different security properties), there generally aren't any intermediate hops in Bluetooth connections, so there is no point in each application adding its own encryption layer: they can just request the use of an encrypted link.